# Email Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am checking the validation for email using regular expression its working fine for me. What if the user give some dummy mailid in the textbox?

How can i check whether the entered mail is valid or not without telling the user to login to that mail and click subscribe link?

Is it possible to check like this..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you want to use the send/reply route?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/2291

Answer (score 4):

> How can i check whether the entered
>   mail is valid or not without telling
>   the user to login to that mail and
>   click subscribe link?

You can not. Point. Thanks to spammers no email server wil lbehave. Some will send you "user doesn ot exist" errors, some will even swallow them.

Plus, legally, youalso have to make sure the subscriber actually OWNS the mailbox, and is not entering someone else email.

Answer (score 3):

The only way which i think is

Send an email to the specified email address , if you don't got a bounced email , email is valid provided by user

Answer (score 2):

Without verifying that the user can actually read email, you can't ensure it's that user's real account.

Many domains accept all mail, and use it for spam analysis on invalid accounts, and a user can easily provide 'real' accounts they don't control. (eg: sales@example.com)